# What default perms would MySQL assign to this user form: 'user'@''

Tags: mysql

Specifically, that's a user with a blank (empty) host field. Created with a GRANT of the form:

```
GRANT ALL on *.database to 'username'@'' identified by 'password';
```

I've tried reading through the MySQL docs on GRANT, but to no avail.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can enable wildcard hosts in mysql. But it isn't recommended

Comment: I've been hitting MySQL error 1449 whilst mysqldumping. I don't know how entries have been created in this form.. but they have. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a host named with the empty string on your network (i.e. the root of your DNS), that permission will never be matched.

Comment: Great, thanks. The reason I need to know is hitting this error whilst mysqldumping. I don't know how entries have been created in this form.. but they have. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql